Change Windows 2022 Server AD Password using PHP 8.3
I am wondering whether anyone here have came across the same problem and/or have a solution for it. I have dealt with LDAP before and made changes to account's password using PHP, and have been successful implementing password changing scripts without any issue. This time the pair is PHP 8.3 and Windows Server 2022 Active Directory and somehow keep bumping into "insufficient access" error. The protocol I use is LDAPS, and uses Domain Administrator role as service but the error persists. Thank you in advance for the help. The following is a snippet of my code :
 $ldap_conn = ldap_connect($ldap_server);
if (!$ldap_conn) {
    die("Could not connect to LDAP server.");
}
ldap_set_option(NULL, LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_REQUIRE_CERT, LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_NEVER);
ldap_set_option($ldap_conn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
ldap_set_option($ldap_conn, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);

// Bind as the service account
if (!ldap_bind($ldap_conn, $ldap_user, $ldap_password)) {
    die("Could not bind to LDAP server.");
}

// Find the user's DN
$filter = "(sAMAccountName=$username)";
$search = ldap_search($ldap_conn, $ldap_dn, $filter);
$entries = ldap_get_entries($ldap_conn, $search);

if ($entries['count'] > 0) {
    $user_dn = $entries[0]['dn'];

    // Bind as the user to verify the current password
    if (ldap_bind($ldap_conn, $user_dn, $current_password)) {
        // Encode the new password
        $new_password_encoded = "\"" . $new_password . "\"";
        $new_password_encoded = mb_convert_encoding($new_password_encoded, "UTF-16LE");

        $entry = ["unicodePwd" => $new_password_encoded];

        // Attempt to change the password
        //if (ldap_modify($ldap_conn, $user_dn, $entry)) {
        if (ldap_mod_replace($ldap_conn,$user_dn,$entry)){
            echo "Password changed successfully.";
        } else {
            echo "Error changing password.";
        }
    } else {
        echo "Current password is incorrect.";
    }
} else {
    echo "User not found.";
}

ldap_unbind($ldap_conn);

